# Ember CLI Build with custom CMS settings

Tags: build, ember-cli

Business Problem: For a series of Ember applications, allow colors, logos, specific pieces of content to be controlled by a CMS to support white/grey labeling of software.

Proposed Solution: An Ember CLI addon would be created that, at build time, pulls in the appropriate stylesheet rules, logo URLs, etc and inject the content into the appropriate trees.

Initial implementation for the addon:

```
// index.js
/* jshint node: true */
'use strict';

const BroccoliMergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
const broccoliSource = require('broccoli-source');
const UnwatchedDir = broccoliSource.UnwatchedDir;
const apiFactory = require('./lib/cms-integration-addon/api.js');
const writeFile = require('write');

module.exports = {
  name: 'cms-integration-addon',
  cmsIntegrationConfig: {},
  isDevelopingAddon() {
    return true;
  },

  included(app) {
    const config = app.project.config(app.env)['cms-integration'] || {};
    this.cmsIntegrationConfig = config;
  },

  treeForAddon() {
    let tree = this._super.treeForAddon.apply(this, arguments);

    const cmsDetailsSource = new UnwatchedDir(this.app.project.root + '/tmp/cms-integration-addon');
    tree = new BroccoliMergeTrees([tree, cmsDetailsSource]);

    return tree;
  },

  preBuild() {
    const cms = apiFactory(this.cmsIntegrationConfig);
    return cms.fetchSettings().then((settings) => {
      const configPath = `${this.app.project.root}/tmp/cms-integration-addon/config/my-config.js`;

      return writeFile(configPath, `export default ${JSON.stringify(settings)}`);
    });
  }
};
```

The problem is that with this code the appropriate JSON object from the CMS does not get inserted into `vendor.js` under the `cms-integration-addon` module as I would expect. *However*, if I change `treeForAddon` to `treeForApp` the settings object does get inserted into `app-name.js` under the app's module. This is not ideal and it is better if this code is injected under the addon's module.

What am I missing to be able to inject my JSON object into the addon's module?

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to determine why `treeForApp` allowed injecting but the other `treeFor*` methods did not I was able to determine how to appropriately inject code into the addon at build time. Using the example above a couple changes need to be made along with the addition of a new `app.import()` call in `ember-cli-build.js`.

1. Change the output path for the JSON object to live under `vendor/` instead of `tmp/`. According to [Ember CLI documentation](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#compiling-assets) only files living under `bower_components` and `vendor` can be imported into your app.
2. Change the actual file output to the `vendor/` directory to adhere to AMD format using `define()`.
3. Add the following line to your `ember-cli-build.js` file:

   `app.import('vendor/cms-integration/config/my-config.js');`

At this point you should see the appropriate object injected into your vendor.js file and you can use it by calling:

`import CmsSettings from 'cms-integration/config/my-config';`